# Calling a Rest API from tfs extension with JScript

Tags: javascript, api, tfs, azure-devops

I am basicly using 3 diffrent JS methods to get the data from the api but they return the error 405: Method Not Allowed but server has the get method in it as allowed. It is using path for the variable so I am wondering if it is related to that.

Here are the Codes for Methods that i call the API.

Fetch Method;

```
    function getCompleted(queryParam) {
                    $('#loader').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('#loaded').addClass('hidden');
                    fetch("****/fullprofile/" + queryParam, {
                            method: "GET", headers: {
                                    "User": "*****",
                                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                            }
                    })
                            .then((data) => {
                                    const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
                                    console.log(contentType);
                                    return data.json()
                            })
                            .then(function (result) {
                                    ResponseBody = result;

                                    $('#loader').addClass('hidden');
                                    $('#loaded').removeClass('hidden');
                            }).catch(function () {
                                    $('#loader').addClass('hidden');
                                    $('#loaded').removeClass('hidden');
                            });
            }
```

HTTP Request Method;

```
function httprequest(queryParam2) {
                    $('#loader').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('#loaded').addClass('hidden');
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.withCredentials=true;
                    var url = "*****/fullprofile/";
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
                            console.log(this.responseText);
                            console.log(data);                                
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", url + queryParam2);
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("User", "*****");
                    xmlhttp.send();
            }
```

Ajax Method;

```
function ajax(queryParam3) {

                    $.ajax({
                            url: "****/fullprofile/" + queryParam3,
                            "method":"GET",
                            "headers":{
                                    "User":"EBT\\****"
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                    ResponseBody = data;
                            console.log(data);
                            }
                    });   
            }
```

Thank you all for the advices and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason was sending with headers; it returns options that needs to be responded again and it wasn't worth doing in JS so i decided to make a gateway api to use the api i have with header.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the resource you are trying to consult does not use the verb GET.

you have to confirm with which verb the resource is obtained

Look here:
[405 Method Not Allowed MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)

Confirm in the documentation of the api with which verb that resource is requested. I could be POST, PUT etc

[Here you can look explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

Comment: I can call the same api with postman using get and i checked the api swagger for get too.